# Un-pause game button not working

Tags: godot, godot-4

I can successfully pause my game with Godot 4.1 with:

```
func _process(delta):
        
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("action_quit"):
        print("pause...")
        pause()


func pause():
    Globals.game_paused = !Globals.game_paused
    print("game paused? " + str(Globals.game_paused))
    get_tree().paused = ! get_tree().paused
```

But that's as good as it gets: Once the "action_quit" key is hit the game is permanently paused from this point on.

I've got a sneaking suspicion that *_process* is on holiday at this point and `get_tree().paused = ! get_tree().paused` isn't being processed. I may be wrong.

How do I check for a keyboard call to un-pause the game?

Answer (score 2):

The `process_mode` of the `Node` controls when their `Script` get to run.

---

By default `process_mode` is set to `PROCESS_MODE_INHERIT`, which mean they take the value from their parent.

And, also by default, the `process_mode` of the `root` of the `SceneTree` is set to `PROCESS_MODE_PAUSABLE`, which means that when you set the `paused` property of the `SceneTree` to `true`, the `Node` will stop executing its `Script`...

And since everything else has `process_mode` set to `PROCESS_MODE_INHERIT` by default, then every `Script` stops executing too.

---

To be able to remove the pause you need an `Script` to run when `paused` is `true`...

That means changing the `process_mode` of the `Node` that has the `Script`.

Aside from `PROCESS_MODE_INHERIT` and `PROCESS_MODE_PAUSABLE`, your options are:

- `PROCESS_MODE_WHEN_PAUSED` which is the opposite of `PROCESS_MODE_PAUSABLE`. It will make the `Script` only run when `paused` is true. Since you want to use the same script to pause and unpause, this won't work for you.
- `PROCESS_MODE_ALWAYS` which makes the `Script` run regardless of `paused`. This is what you want.
- There is also `PROCESS_MODE_DISABLED` that makes the `Script` never run. This is sometimes useful to temporarily disable entire `Script` from code.

---

I want to reiterate that this is about disabling entire `Script`s, not just `_process` (which you can do with `set_process`) or any other specific methods. *So, no, `_unhandled_input` won't work.*

Comment: Oh I forget that I've changed the node process mode to always. By bad, answer deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that the `_process`, `_physics_process`, `_input`, and `_input_event` functions will not be called when a Node is paused. However signals continue to work and cause their connected function to run.

As such you can solve this problem by making a popup or panel to handle pausing. Make sure to set its pause mode to `WhenPaused` - doing so will ensure that it & its children will work when paused. Then you can add code so that the pressing the pause button will enable & show the pause screen:

```
func _on_pause_button_pressed():
    get_tree().paused = true
    $pause_popup.show()
```

To unpause and resume the game, do the opposite when the pause screen is closed:

```
func _on_pause_popup_close_pressed():
    $pause_popup.hide()
    get_tree().paused = false
```

You can find more information about this in the [pausing games and process mode documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/pausing_games.html).